Transparent stickyHeader shows items behind
I'm looking into a way of having my stickyheader with a transparent background, this is because my background has a gradient and I need the header to have a transparent background.
Reproducible example
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun Example() {
    Box(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            .drawBackgroundGradient()
            .clipToBounds()
    ) {
        LazyColumn {
            stickyHeader {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(Color.Transparent)
                        .padding(top = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp)
                ) {
                    Card(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Gray),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),
                        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = TransparentBackground)
                    ) {
                        Row(
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp),
                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                        ) {

                            Icon(
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 16.dp),
                                painter = rememberVectorPainter(Icons.Filled.Warning),
                                contentDescription = "Disclaimer icon",
                                tint = Color.Yellow
                            )

                            Text(
                                text = "Test copy text of banner",
                                style = TS_Helvetica_400.copy(
                                    lineHeight = 15.sp
                                ),
                                fontSize = 14.sp,
                                color = Color.White
                            )
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
            items(fakeList) { item ->
                Text(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), text = item, color = Color.White)
            }
        }
    }
}

val baseList = listOf("name 1", "name 2", "name 3")

// Create a list of 100 elements by repeating baseList
val fakeList = List(100 / baseList.size) { baseList }.flatten() + baseList.take(100 % baseList.size)

fun Modifier.drawBackgroundGradient(): Modifier {
    return this.drawBehind {
        val gradientColors =
            listOf(Color(0xFF6A66FF).copy(alpha = 0.2f), Color.Transparent)

        // Draw the background color
        drawRect(color = Color.Black)

        // Draw the first radial gradient circle
        drawCircle(
            brush = Brush.radialGradient(
                colors = gradientColors,
                center = Offset(size.width * 0.1f, size.height * 0.5f),
                radius = 800.dp.toPx()
            ),
            radius = 800.dp.toPx(),
            center = Offset(size.width * 0.1f, size.height * 0.5f)
        )

        // Draw the second radial gradient circle
        drawCircle(
            brush = Brush.radialGradient(
                colors = gradientColors,
                center = Offset(size.width * 0.9f, size.height * 0.9f),
                radius = 500.dp.toPx()
            ),
            radius = 500.dp.toPx(),
            center = Offset(size.width * 0.9f, size.height * 0.9f)
        )
    }
}

I have been trying some workarounds but they do not include the stickyHeader component, I know it is experimental, but is there a way maybe that the items are not showing behind when dragging but instead cut at some kind of boxed content?

Please provide a [mre], one that we can execute ourselves.

Example provided @Leviathan

What is TransparentBackground? Specifically, what is its alpha value?

Color.Transparent.copy(alpha = 0.7f) You can also use Color.Transparent, is the same

To the best of my knowledge, LazyColumn will always scroll items behind the stickyHeader. You can achieve your desired UI by separating the header and wrapping it in a Column along with LazyColumn.
Here is the updated code:
@Composable
fun Example() {
Column(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .drawBackgroundGradient()
        .clipToBounds()
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.Transparent)
            .padding(top = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp)
    ) {
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Gray),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),
            colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Color.Transparent)
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {

                Icon(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 16.dp),
                    painter = rememberVectorPainter(Icons.Filled.Warning),
                    contentDescription = "Disclaimer icon",
                    tint = Color.Yellow
                )

                Text(
                    text = "Test copy text of banner",
                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                    color = Color.White
                )
            }

        }

    }
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
        items(fakeList) { item ->
            Text(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), text = item, color = Color.White)
        }
    }
  }
}


Thanks a lot for your answer ! I did this very same approach at first as a workaround, but I was trying to see if there is a way to make stickyHeader work

Glad I could help!
